# Empty rows in a GridView binded to a table on a sql server won't update / delete

Tags: asp.net

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, C# ASP.NET 4.

I have a table on the sql server created with this T-SQL(including data):

```
CREATE DATABASE [someDatabase]
GO
USE [someDatabase]

CREATE TABLE someTable (someCode [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, someDescription [nvarchar](50) NULL);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[someTable] (someDescription) VALUES (''),('row 2, 1st non empty line'),('3'),(''),('5th row');
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[someTable]
```

I also have a Default.aspx file containing a Gridview with a ConnectionString to the above table, including Edit and Delete options (templates) - no code behind:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="someCode" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="someCode" HeaderText="someCode" 
                InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="someCode" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="someDescription" HeaderText="someDescription" 
                SortExpression="someDescription" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:someDatabaseConnectionString %>" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [someTable] WHERE [someCode] = @original_someCode AND (([someDescription] = @original_someDescription) OR ([someDescription] IS NULL AND @original_someDescription IS NULL))" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [someTable] ([someDescription]) VALUES (@someDescription)" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [someTable]" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [someTable] SET [someDescription] = @someDescription WHERE [someCode] = @original_someCode AND (([someDescription] = @original_someDescription) OR ([someDescription] IS NULL AND @original_someDescription IS NULL))">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_someCode" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_someDescription" Type="String" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="someDescription" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="someDescription" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_someCode" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_someDescription" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

It looks like the GridView is nicely bound the database's table. However, I have a problem when **using optimistic concurrency**. Then I can't neither delete rows that has no description, nor I can't update those in Edit mode.

The GridView looks fine in a browser (IE9, Chrome 18), but when I try to delete one of the rows with no description it doesn't work. When I click on Edit of one of the no description rows, I get the chance to type a new value, however, when I click Update nothing happens.

**There is no problem** to edit/delete rows with someDescription filled. When **not** using optimistic concurrency the edit and delete work for the empty descriptions too.

Is it normal for GridView to malfunction? Is there a workaround?

Is there an access to the validation tools of the GridView template while it is in edit or delete mode of rows?

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen `OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"`, `OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"` or `OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"` events in your code above. In order to Edit/Update and Delete as you added in GridView `'<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />'` you have to use those events.

something like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
  GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
  BindData();
}
```

visit this link: [Add, Edit, update, Delete gridview](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1360/add-edit-update-delete-gridview/)

Comment: It should work without code behind. The matter of fact is does when it is not in using optimistic concurrency mode. Why everything works when not using optimistic concurrency? Or the real question, why the GridView isn't fully functional particularly in this mode? Remember, the edit / delete works in this mode in cases there is some text in the someDescription field.